# Randomization in clinical trials

Tags: clinical-trials, random-allocation

Randomization in clinical trials is a phenomena where each individual has equal chance to receive a treatment. How can you express randomization mathematically.

Comment: If there are $M$ groups, then you can consider the groups as arising from a multinomial distribution.

Comment: That would have to be a multinomial distribution in which all the $p_i$'s are equal.

Comment: Thanks @Demetri, will this be correct, Mathematically,  randomization  can  be  described  as  multinational  distribution  where  an  investigator assign $M$ treatments to $N$ investigation units by performing $N$ repeated and independent trials with probability $p_i$ where $i= 1,2...N$ for each trial to receive a treatment.

Comment: You need to specify the randomization scheme; there are many different ways to randomize.

Comment: @gung  I was trying to explain randomization in general

Comment: Simple randomisation, which is what is being described in these comments, is not used in practice. People actually use permuted blocks or stratification or minimisation.

Comment: I'm not sure it's meaningful to think of there being a "randomization in general". A mathematical formalization of 1 randomization scheme would be incorrect for another.